# GatsbyImage className ignores gatsby-plugin-styled-jsx but works with CSS modules

Tags: gatsby

I'm working on a code as simple as:

```
<GatsbyImage className="card-image-wrapper" image={logoImage} alt="company image" />
```

If I define de `.card-image-wrapper` in a CSS module all works fine, the class is applied to the DOM element and CSS sentences are applied.

The problem arise when using the `gatsby-plugin-styled-jsx`. In this case the class is applied to the DOM element but no CSS sentences are applied.

Comment: How are you configuring the `gatsby-plugin-styled-jsx` plugin?

Comment: Hi @FerranBuireu, I put without any options, just `gatsby-plugin-styled-jsx`

Comment: Does it have the same behavior in `gatsby develop`as well as `gatsby build`?

Comment: nop, it doesnt works no matter develop or build :(